# Transaction Management for spring Kafka with Database/MQ interaction

Tags: spring, spring-boot, transactions, spring-kafka, spring-transactions

We are trying to implement transaction management within our spring Kafka consumers.

We have Kafka consumers listening to messages from topic A -> database update/insert -> Produce Kafka message on topic B.

The issue I am facing is, when database transaction commit fails, the send operation on topic B is not rolled back. So the system is in inconsistent state.

The other scenarios work as expected.

For eg:

1. Read msg from kafka -> db interaction -> kafka send : If kafka send fails, db txn is not committed and read message's offset is not committed.
2. Read msg from kafka -> db interaction -> kafka send : If commit of consumed message's offset fails, kafka send and db does not commit.

PS: I am aware that kafka does not support XA transactions. I did see a few resources mentioning the use of ChaintedTransactionManager, as per the docs it is deprecated from spring data core version 2.5 so would not want to use that preferably. Any suggestion is appreciated.

I am putting code snippets below -

Main:

```
@KafkaHandler
@Transactional(transactionManager = "kafkaTxM", propagation = Propagation.REQUIRED)
public void receiveCreationMessage(String event){
 
  // saves into database
  dao.saveDraft(event);
  
  // sends kafka message
  sendMQAdapterKafkaEvent(initiateReqMq, convertedEvent);
 
}
 
 @Transactional(transactionManager = "kafkaTxM", propagation = Propagation.REQUIRED)
 public void saveDraft(@NonNull String event) {
 
    entityManager.joinTransaction();
    entityManager.persist(event);
}
 
@Transactional(transactionManager = "kafkaTxM", propagation = Propagation.REQUIRED)
public void sendMQAdapterKafkaEvent(String mqName, Object message) throws 
 
            kafkaTemplate.send(topicName, msgKey, message)
}
```

Application.properties

```
spring.kafka.producer.transaction-id-prefix=txnId-
spring.kafka.consumer.properties.isolation.level=read_committed
spring.kafka.properties.transactional-id=trans-id-
```

Kafka listener container factory:

```
@Bean(KafkaConstants.ContainerFactoryNames.MANUAL_COMMIT_CONTAINER_FACTORY)
    @Autowired()
    public ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<Object, Object> manualCommitKafkaListenerContainerFactory(
            @NonNull final ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactoryConfigurer configurer,
            @NonNull final KafkaProperties kafkaProperties,
            @NonNull final RecordMessageConverter converter,
            @NonNull final ErrorHandler errorHandler,
            @NotNull final RetryTemplate retryTemplate,
            @NotNull @Qualifier("kafkaTxM") @Lazy final KafkaTransactionManager kafkaTransactionManager) {

        ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<Object, Object> factory = new ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<>();

        val consumerProperties = kafkaProperties.buildConsumerProperties();
        consumerProperties.put(ConsumerConfig.ENABLE_AUTO_COMMIT_CONFIG, "false");
        val consumerFactory = new DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory<Object, Object>(consumerProperties);


        factory.getContainerProperties().setAckMode(ContainerProperties.AckMode.MANUAL_IMMEDIATE);
        factory.getContainerProperties().setTransactionManager(kafkaTransactionManager);

        factory.setErrorHandler(new SeekToCurrentErrorHandler(new FixedBackOff(0L, 0L)));
        factory.setAfterRollbackProcessor(new TestRollbackProcesor(errorHandler, kafkaTransactionManager, new FixedBackOff(0L, 0L)));
        configurer.configure(factory, consumerFactory);

        return factory;
    }
```

Kafka producer factory –

```
@Bean
public ProducerFactory<?, ?> kafkaProducerFactory(final KafkaProperties kafkaProperties) throws IOException {

    val factory = new DefaultKafkaProducerFactory<>(kafkaProperties.buildProducerProperties());
    val transactionIdPrefix = kafkaProperties.getProducer().getTransactionIdPrefix();
    if (transactionIdPrefix != null) {
        factory.setTransactionIdPrefix(transactionIdPrefix);
    }
    factory.transactionCapable();
    return factory;
}
```

Kafka tx manager bean –

```
@Bean(name = "kafkaTxM")
public KafkaTransactionManager kafkaTransactionManager(final MyConfiguration myConfig,
                                                       final KafkaProperties kafkaProperties) throws IOException {
    KafkaTransactionManager ktm = new KafkaTransactionManager(kafkaProducerFactory(myConfig, kafkaProperties));;
    ktm.setTransactionSynchronization(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.SYNCHRONIZATION_ON_ACTUAL_TRANSACTION);
    return ktm;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> 13:20:20.798 [org.springframework.kafka.KafkaListenerEndpointContainer#0-0-C-1] ERROR o.s.k.l.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer - Transaction rolled back

The `Kafka` transaction is indeed rolled back.

Perhaps your consumer is using the default `isolation.level` (`read_uncommitted`).

With Kafka, the producer record(s) is always written to the log, followed by a marker block that indicates whether the transaction was committed or rolled back.

Consumers must have `isolation.level` `read_committed` to skip over rolled-back records.

Comment: Thanks Gary for quick reply. My consumer indeed has the isolation.level=read_committed in the properties like so-

spring.kafka.consumer.properties.isolation.level=read_committed.


Is there anything more worth trying?

Comment: Also, I think kafka transaction is getting rolled back for sure but the production of msg is committed already before the exception and so looks like it does not roll back.

Comment: Config looks good; I suggest TRACE logging for `o.s.transaction` and `o.s.kafka` to see what's happening..

Comment: Putting logs at this medium blog for now - https://medium.com/@bansi.derashri/kafka-transaction-manager-logs-b3e029bdd8be

Comment: Something raw like pastebin or a GitHub gist would be easier.

Comment: I see what's happening; you are synchronizing the DB transaction with the KafkaTransaction; the KafkaTransaction commits first followed by the DB, which rolls back. The `@Transactional` must specify the entity manager transaction so it commits or rolls back first. You do not need to refer to the kafka transaction manager anywhere except in the container.

Comment: Thanks for suggesting alternatives over medium article. Will keep that in mind.
Regarding the suggestion to use entity manager transaction so it commits or rolls back first does not work as expected in another scenario. For example, lets say DB commit went fine but kafka send to topic B failed then db commit does not rollback. :'(

Comment: I have a use case where I need to be as close as possible to "Either everything commits or everything rolls back". Best I can achieve would be following scenario,
1. Commit consumed message's offset
2. Commit DB txn
3. Commit kafka send to topic B

However I don't seem to be capable of playing around with commit order.

Comment: That is because all Spring can do is "Best Efforts 1 Phase Commit". Kafka does not support distributed (JTA)/(XA) transactions. https://www.infoworld.com/article/2077963/distributed-transactions-in-spring--with-and-without-xa.html You have two choices - write a compensating update to reverse the DB update or make your listener idempotent, but storing the topic/partition/offset along with the data in the DB, so you can detect that it is already processed.

Comment: The commit order is as I described - Kafka then DB when using synchronization, DB then Kafka when using nested transactions. You can't have both on the same listener.

Comment: TRACE level logs are now here at github gist - https://gist.github.com/bansii1/7f046498d9053992f9b1fdc2c49ef44e

Comment: Ok. I have been through this article [ after your comment to some other so answer took me there :) ]. Two more questions please.
1. Why does kafka not support XA transactions? Do we have any plans to introduce XA transactions for kafka in future releases?

Comment: 2. Doc here suggests we can implement the Ordered interface to influence their execution order. But I don't see kafka txn manager or any other tx manager calls getOrder() method before committing so wanted to know your thoughts on this [https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/5.3.10/javadoc-api/org/springframework/transaction/reactive/TransactionSynchronization.html?is-external=true]

Comment: `1. Why does kafka not support XA transactions?` - probably because it is very hard to implement; I can't comment on plans, I am not on the Kafka team, but I very much doubt if there are any plans. XA transactions are very, very expensive (performance wise and implementation) and are generally out of favor, especially in the microservices world where compensating or idempotent updates are preferred. The `Ordered` reference means the order that synchronizations are executed after the primary transaction completes (you can synchronize multiple transactions with the primary one).